# methods called twice: once with and once without parameters; how to prevent this behaviour?

Tags: python, kivy

I try to implement sort action methods for displaying data in different varities.
The code seems to work, it does what I expect it to do,

but the methods "sort_by_columnName" (eg: sort_by_customer, sort_by_order, and so on) in class: "Order_DataSource" are called twice -  once with and once without params,

I'm considering - what's going wrong with this code and how to prevent this behaviour?

python 3.8

```
import abc
from abc import ABCMeta
from typing import List
# kivy 2.0
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


kv = '''
#: import cust_rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex


<Concept_Datagrid>:
    id: gridview
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: cust_rgba('#8a8e8a')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<Custom_HeaderCell>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: cust_rgba('#0b0f0a')
            Line:
                width: 1
                rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            id: header_label
            color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: cust_rgba('#eaeaea')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            id: sort_box
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            Button:
                id: sort_asc_btn
                background_color: cust_rgba('#3aeaea')
                text: 'sort Asc'
                on_release: root.sort_by(sort_id=self.text, sort_value=header_label.text)
            Button:
                id: sort_desc_btn
                background_color: cust_rgba('#3aeaea')
                text: 'sort Desc'
                on_release: root.sort_by(sort_id=self.text, sort_value=header_label.text)

'''


class Base_DataSource(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return (
            hasattr(subclass, 'source_data') and callable(subclass.source_data) and
            hasattr(subclass, 'table_keys') and callable(subclass.table_keys) and
            hasattr(subclass, 'sort_methods') and callable(subclass.sort_methods) or
            NotImplemented
        )
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def source_data(self):
        # returns data as List[dict]
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def table_keys(self):
        # returns table's columns name
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def sort_methods(self):
        # returns datasource column specific sorting methods name
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sort_dummy(self):
        # special method for sorting: nothing to do but important to be here;"
        pass


class Order_DataSource(EventDispatcher, Base_DataSource):

    data: List[dict] = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Order_DataSource, self).__init__()
        self.data = self.source_data()
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def source_data() -> List[dict]:
        return list([
            {'id': 1, 'customer': 'otto b', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'DE_BER'},
            {'id': 2, 'customer': 'boris a', 'order_group': 'og_2', 'destination': 'UK_LD'},
            {'id': 3, 'customer': 'francine b', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'FR_PAR'},
            {'id': 4, 'customer': 'franz w', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'AT_W01'},
            {'id': 5, 'customer': 'cleopatra a', 'order_group': 'og_5', 'destination': 'EGY_KAI'},
            {'id': 6, 'customer': 'jorge c', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'SP_MAD'},
            {'id': 7, 'customer': 'aras l', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'LT_VIL'},
            {'id': 8, 'customer': 'uri m', 'order_group': 'og_8', 'destination': 'RUS_MOC'},
            {'id': 9, 'customer': 'joseph s', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'DE_BAV'},
            {'id': 10, 'customer': 'julie g', 'order_group': 'og_2', 'destination': 'CH_URI'},
            {'id': 11, 'customer': 'cindy l', 'order_group': 'og_3', 'destination': 'US_NY'},
            {'id': 12, 'customer': 'jair b', 'order_group': 'og_4', 'destination': 'BR_BRA'},
            {'id': 13, 'customer': 'akiko a', 'order_group': 'og_5', 'destination': 'JAP_HON'},
            {'id': 14, 'customer': 'lana s', 'order_group': 'og_1', 'destination': 'SLO_LUB'},
            {'id': 15, 'customer': 'adanna u', 'order_group': 'og_7', 'destination': 'NIG_UL'},
            {'id': 16, 'customer': 'ljudmila c', 'order_group': 'og_8', 'destination': 'RUS_PET'},
        ])

    def table_keys(self) -> List[str]:
        dict_keys = []
        for key_, value_ in self.source_data()[0].items():
            dict_keys.append(key_)
        return dict_keys

    def sort_methods(self) -> dict:
        return {'id': None, 'customer': self.sort_by_customer,
                'order_group': self.sort_by_order, 'destination': self.sort_by_destination}

    def sort_by_id(self, *args) -> List[dict]:
        print(f'{self.sort_by_id.__name__} with args: {args}')
        if args:
            the_data = self.source_data()
            if args[0]['sort_id'] in 'sort Asc':
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['id'], reverse=False)
            else:
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['id'], reverse=True)
            return sorted_data
        pass

    def sort_by_customer(self, *args) -> List[dict]:
        print(f'{self.sort_by_customer.__name__} with args: {args}')
        if args:
            the_data = self.source_data()
            if args[0]['sort_id'] in 'sort Asc':
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['customer'], reverse=False)
            else:
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['customer'], reverse=True)
            return sorted_data
        pass

    def sort_by_order(self, *args) -> List[dict]:
        print(f'{self.sort_by_order.__name__} with args: {args}')
        if args:
            the_data = self.source_data()
            if args[0]['sort_id'] in 'sort Asc':
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['order_group'], reverse=False)
            else:
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['order_group'], reverse=True)
            return sorted_data
        pass

    def sort_by_destination(self, *args) -> List[dict]:
        print(f'{self.sort_by_destination.__name__} with args: {args}')
        if args:
            the_data = self.source_data()
            if args[0]['sort_id'] in 'sort Asc':
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['destination'], reverse=False)
            else:
                sorted_data = sorted(the_data, key=lambda sCol: sCol['destination'], reverse=True)
            return sorted_data
        pass

    pass


class Custom_HeaderCell(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.datagrid = kwargs['master']
        self.datasource = kwargs['source']
        self.cell_text = kwargs['cell_text']
        self.ids.header_label.text = self.cell_text
        if kwargs['sort_method'] is None:
            self.ids.sort_box.remove_widget(self.ids.sort_asc_btn)
            self.ids.sort_box.remove_widget(self.ids.sort_desc_btn)
            self.ids.sort_box.add_widget(Button(text='no sort'))
            self.wanted_method = self.datasource.sort_dummy
        else:
            if kwargs['sort_method'] not in ['None', None]:
                for method in dir(kwargs['sort_method'].__self__):
                    if method in kwargs['sort_method'].__name__:
                        self.wanted_method = kwargs['sort_method']
                self.ids.sort_asc_btn.on_release = self.wanted_method
                self.ids.sort_desc_btn.on_release = self.wanted_method

    def sort_by(self, **kwargs):
        print(f'Custom_HeaderCell.sort_by kwargs {kwargs}')
        if callable(self.wanted_method):
            self.datagrid.data_view.data = self.wanted_method(kwargs)
        pass


class Concept_Datagrid(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, datasource):
        super(Concept_Datagrid, self).__init__()
        self.datasource = datasource
        self.add_widget(Header(self, list(self.datasource.table_keys())))
        self.data_view = DataView(self.datasource)
        self.add_widget(self.data_view)

    pass


class Header(BoxLayout):
    size_hint = 1, None

    def __init__(self, dataGrid, columns, **kwargs):
        super(Header, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height = self.size[1] * 2 / len(columns)  # this is not what I really want!
        the_header = HeaderView(dataGrid, columns)
        self.add_widget(the_header)
    pass


class HeaderView(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, dataGrid, columns: list, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        self.columns = columns

        for column_name in self.columns:

            if dataGrid.datasource.sort_methods()[column_name]:
                sortMethod = dataGrid.datasource.sort_methods()[column_name]
            else:
                sortMethod = None

            self.add_widget(Custom_HeaderCell(
                cell_text=str(column_name),
                sort_method=sortMethod,
                source=dataGrid.datasource,
                master=dataGrid)
            )

    pass


class DataView(GridLayout):
    data = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, datasource: Order_DataSource):
        super(DataView, self).__init__()
        self.data = datasource.source_data()
        self.cols = len(datasource.table_keys())  # set number of columns to GridLayout,
        pass

    def _update_view(self):
        if self.children:
            self.clear_widgets()
        for entity in self.data:
            for item in entity.values():
                lbl = Label()
                lbl.text = str(item)
                self.add_widget(lbl)

    def on_data(self, *args):
        self._update_view()

    pass


class Test_App(App):
    Window.size = (800, 600)
    title = str('minimal datagrid app')

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        source = Order_DataSource()
        concept_test = Concept_Datagrid(source)
        return concept_test
        pass
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test_App().run()
    pass
```

Comment: If you want helpful answers, you've got to narrow down your own code first. I'd suggest though, raise an exception based on if there are parameters or not so you can see where it's being called from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you are specifying `on_release` actions twice, so the specified method gets called twice. In your `__init__()` method of `Custom_HeaderCell`, you have:

```
            self.ids.sort_asc_btn.on_release = self.wanted_method
            self.ids.sort_desc_btn.on_release = self.wanted_method
```

and in your `kv` you have:

```
        Button:
            id: sort_asc_btn
            background_color: cust_rgba('#3aeaea')
            text: 'sort Asc'
            on_release: root.sort_by(sort_id=self.text, sort_value=header_label.text)
        Button:
            id: sort_desc_btn
            background_color: cust_rgba('#3aeaea')
            text: 'sort Desc'
            on_release: root.sort_by(sort_id=self.text, sort_value=header_label.text)
```

So you are setting `on_release` twice which results in it being called twice.